# How to get rid of pygame 2.0.0.dev6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pygame, python-3.8

i just installed python on my mac and i had also installed VS code with it. Later i tried installing pygame but it didn't work so i found another version that installed the version that is not stable, or pygame2.0.0.dev6 - i think that is have you type it. So that went succesfull, but after i found out why i was not being able to install the stable version, so now i want to get rid of  pygame2.0.0.dev6 and install the stable version because in my VS code editor it keeps saying that it is using pygame2.0.0.dev6 even when i have the stable version installed.

Please all i want is to uninstall pygame2.0.0.dev6. I tried going to the documentation and i tried uninstalling from the terminal itself but i still cannot uninstall it. Help would me much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip3 uninstall pygame==2.0.0.dev6`

Windows users should use `pip` instead of `pip3`

**Always use virtual environments. This version problem will be mitigated.**